# PHP: Storing picture in the file directory, image name in db and retrieving an image

Tags: php

After doing research, I found that it is more recommended to save the image name in database and the actual image in a file directory. Two of the  few reasons is that it is more safer and the pictures load a lot quicker. But I don't really get the point of doing this procedure because every time I retrieve the pictures with the firebug tool i can find out the picture path in the file directory which can lead to potential breach.

Am I doing this correctly or it is not suppose to show the complete file directory path of the image?

PHP for saving image into database

```
$images = retrieve_images();
    insert_images_into_database($images);

    function retrieve_images()
    {        
        $images = explode(',', $_GET['i']);

        return $images;
    }

    function insert_images_into_database($images)
    {
        if(!$images) //There were no images to return
            return false;        

       $pdo = get_database_connection();

        foreach($images as $image)
        {

            $path = Configuration::getUploadUrlPath('medium', 'target');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `urlImage` (`image_name`) VALUES ( ? )";

            $prepared = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $prepared->execute(array($image));
            echo ('<div><img src="'. $path . $image . '" /></div>');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking to make your images non-retrievable by non-intended parties?

Comment: The reason for using an image name instead of storing image in the database is because it is not advisable to store images in a database table as it takes up lot of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to achieve what you originally intended to do by storing images in database is still continue to serve image via a PHP script, thus:

1. Shielding your users from knowing the actual path of an image.
2. You can, and should have, images stored outside of your `DocumentRoot`, so that they are not able to be served by web server.

Here's one way you can achieve that through [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php):

```
<?php
// image.php

// Translating file_id to image path and filename
$path = getPathFromFileID($_GET['file_id']);
$image = getImageNameFromFileID($_GET['file_id']);

// Actual full path to the image file
// Hopefully outside of DocumentRoot
$file = $path.$image;

if (userHasPermission()) {
    readfile($file);
}
else {
    // Better if you are actually outputting an image instead of echoing text
    // So that the MIME type remains compatible
    echo "You do not have the permission to load the image";
}

exit;
```

You can then serve the image by using standard HTML:

```
<img src="image.php?file_id=XXXXX">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to protect your images.

See here:

http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/csshtml/protecting-images-using-php-and-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on a project which stores the url path of images on the database (Amazon RDS) and the actual images in a cloud managed file system in Amazon S3.

The decision to do so came primarily with the concern of **price, scalability and ease of implementation.**

**Cheaper:** Firstly, it is cheaper to store data in a file system (Amazon S3) compared to a database (Amazon EC2 / RDS).

**Scalable:** And since the repository of images may grow pretty big in the future, you might also need to ensure that you have the adequate capacity to serve them. On this point, it is easier to scale up a filesystem compared to a database. In fact, if you are using cloud storage (like Amazon S3), you don't even need to worry about having not enough space as it has been managed for you by Amazon! you would just need to pay for what you use.

**Ease of Implementation:** In terms of implementation, storing images in a file system is much easier. If you were to serve images directly from databases, you would probably need to implement additional logic to convert blob files into html src blob strings to serve images. And from the look of it, this might actually take up quite substantial processing power which might slow your web server down.

On the other hand, if you were to use a filesystem, all you would require is to put down the url path of the image from the database to the src attribute of the image and its all done!

**Security:** As for security of the images, i have changed the image name to a timestamp concatenated with a random string so that it will prove really difficult for someone to browse for pictures without knowing the file name.

ie. 1342772480UexbblEY7Xj3Q4VtZ.png

Hope this helps!

NB: Please edit my post if you find anything wrong here! this is just my opinion and everyone is welcome to edit!